# Factory Resetting a Dell Windows 10 Machine

Tags: windows, windows-10, reset

I've got a work PC that I'm now using from a remote office without access to the network on which the domain controllers reside.

It has a number of group policies that making using in this environment difficult. If I factory reset the machine will it revert to a standard windows 10 installation or will it retain the domain settings that were preset by dell? If it maintains the settings then I'm not going to be able to login after the reset because it won't be able to access the domain to verify my credentials

Comment: Does Dell actually preset Windows domain settings? That sounds like something only the corporate IT should do. Are you planning to use the "Reset" option within Windows, or a Dell-provided feature, or a fresh reinstall?

Comment: I'm going to use Window's built in Factory reset. My understanding was that dell could deliver PCs pre-configured with all the group policies, domain settings etc. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Use **Fresh Start** instead of **Reset**